Obtener Id de un elemento html con JS
Tengo un programa para registrar plantas donde al apretar el boton añadir, se agrega un nuevo div con su respectiva ID dependiente de un correlativo que se asigna a todos los datos del div.
mi problema es como puedo obtener el Id de estos div para añadir interacción a los elementos del div.
el id se diseña en base al dato.
Ejemplo.
(este extracto es genérico, JS toma y clona el div y cambia las ID por una con un numero correlativo)
<div id="InsertarNuevaPLanta"> 
 <label for="Nombre">nombre:</label> 
 <input id="Nombre">
  <select id="selectN">
   <option>uno</option>
   <option>dos</option>
   <option>tres</option>
  </select>
</div>

al presionar el botón añadir nueva planta JS clona y genera un nuevo div a partir de "InsertarNuevaPLanta", añadiendo el número 23.
<div id="InsertarNuevaPLanta 23"> 
 <label for="Nombre 23">nombre:</label> 
 <input id="Nombre 23">
  <select id="selectN 23">
   <option>uno</option>
   <option>dos</option>
   <option>tres</option>
  </select>
</div>

mi consulta es:
Cómo puedo obtener el ID de un elemento Input o select
teniendo en consideración que al crear el elemento se añade una nueva ID para las distintas plantas.
para declarar el elemento en JS necesito identificarlo ya sea por nombre, id, class, pero si genero un nombre para todas, me traerá error ya que hay mas de un elemento con el mismo nombre y no me identifica uno en particular.
he intentado con:
document.getElementByID("") -- pero vuelvo al punto de inicio, ya que no conozco ID.
document.getElementClassName("") -- Trae más de un elemento, y necesito identificar a uno (el que se desea modificar)

debes diferenciar entre el value y el mensaje que se muestra Valor 1 .

Coloca el evento inline (ej: onlcick="haceralgo(this)"),así cuando lo clonas, lo haces junto con el evento

Hay muchas formas de hacerlo, depende de dónde quieras utilizar el ID. Tu explicación va bien, solo coloca un ejemplo de una función dónde quieras utilizarlo y diría que con eso, uno de nuestros expertos va tener los elementos para responder a tu pregunta.
